# PyVmMonitor Error " pyvmmonitor-ui was not properly started"

Tags: python-3.x, profiling, pydev, liclipse

According to the [PyVmMontior](http://www.pyvmmonitor.com) Devs, "PyVmMonitor integration is bundled in PyDev itself.." I have been trying to use PyVmMonitor to profile a pyqt5 desktop application I have been developing, however I get the following error when trying to launch with the profiler:

```
Error: pyvmmonitor-ui was not properly started by running: <pyvmmonitor.handle_command_line.CommandLineOptions object at 0x105c8a8d0>
```

The program terminates early, and my pyqt5 main script crashes before any windows are created.

I have tried pointing to the pyvmmonitor-ui (executable) location at:

- /Applications/PyVmMonitor.app
- /Applications/PyVmMonitor/Contents/MacOs/pyvmmonitor-ui
- making an alias for both
- profile modes of Sampling and Deterministic

How do I get PyVmMonitor to work with my script (Preferably through LiClipse/PyDev)?

**Relevant Details:**

Mac OS 10.13.5

LiClipse 5.0.3

PyDev for Eclipse: 6.5.0

Program uses Python 3.6, with the following dependencies managed by conda:

- PyQt5
- numpy
- scipy
- matplotlib
- pyqtgraph
- threading

Comment: Sorry about this, this is a problem in the packaging with newer versions of Mac (so, unfortunately you need to wait for a new release to come out).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Any word on when that might happen?

Comment: Hello @FabioZadrozny, almost 8 months later, also using PyDev 6.5.0.  Is PyVmMonitor going to work with PyDev?